# Disable logger.info output in play framework configuration

Tags: java, playframework

I want to disable logging output in production environment how to configure it ?

Comment: With version of play do you use?

Comment: Play version is 2.0.6

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your framework logger in the application.conf with `logger.play=OFF` or define a logger.xml with `<logger name="play" level="OFF" />`and load it via system property using -Dlogger.resource=path/to/logger.xml or -Dlogger.file=path/to/logger.xml

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/SettingsLogger

Comment: This is my application.conf

`#application.log=INFO
logger.play = OFF`

This is my logger.xml

 `<logger name="play" level="OFF"/>
 <logger name="application" level="OFF" />`

But they are still been appended in debug_log file

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by commenting application.log="INFO" and setting logger.play = OFF